# how to create a unique key for each customer?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code that fetches all the customers from my database. i fetch all the customers in my drop down. Now i want to select a customer and when i submit i want to create a key for the selected customer.

This is my **Controller code:**

```
    public function index()
{
    $id = $this->data['org'] = $this->key_m->get_organisation();

    $this->data['key'] = $this->key_m->genrate_license();

    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/key/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);

}
```

**The View:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">   
            <div class="form-group">            
            <h3><label for="sel1"> Organization Name:</label></h3>
            <select required  name="org-list"  id="org-list" class="form-control">  
                <option value="">Select</option>    
                <?php foreach($org as $value) { ?>              
                <option id="emp"  value="<?php echo $value['org_name'];?>"><?php echo $value['org_name'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
                <?php echo "<br>"; ?>   
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

So i want to save the the id for the customer and the key generated in database. when i select any customer[company here] in the dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your option as below:-

```
<option id="emp"  value="<?php echo $value['org_name'].'|'.md5(uniqid(rand(), true));?>"><?php echo $value['org_name'];?></option>
```

I have used `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` for generating unique key.

And in your controller,

```
$test = explode('|', $_POST['org-list']);
```

echo `$test[0]` gives you `value` and `$test[1]` gives you `key`.

Answer (score 3):

It will generate always different unique string depend on micro-time and random number.

```
<?php
     // Here microtime will be unique everytime
     echo substr(md5(microtime()*rand(0,9999)),0,20); // 20 is length of key
 ?>
```

Comment: i have the code to generate the unique keys but i want to know to generate a key for specific customer and save his generated key